# multi variable in where clause in Laravel

Tags: sql, database, laravel-5, where-clause

I am building a query to give a row with multi variables in Laravel.

```
select * from Fruit where apple = red and banana = raw and orange = 1
```

how could I create a SQL query into Laravel in this condition?

```
$result = Fruit::where('apple ', red , 'banana ', raw , 'orange ', 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it some ways

Solution 1:

```
$result = Fruit::whereApple('red')->whereBanana('raw')->whereOrange('1')->get();
```

Solution 2:

```
$result = Fruit::where('apple', 'red')->where('banana', 'raw')->where('orange', '1')->get();
```

Solution 3:

```
$result = Fruit::where([
    'apple' => 'red',
    'banana' => 'raw',
    'orange' => '1'
])->get();
```

Solution 4:

```
$result = Fruit::where([
    ['apple', '=', 'red'],
    ['banana', '=', 'raw'],
    ['orange', '=', '1']
])
->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for your different solutions :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a recent version of Laravel, then you may define an associative array containing the conditions:

```
$conditions = ['apple' => 'red', 'banana' => 'raw', 'orange' => '1'];
$result = Fruit::where($conditions)->get();
```

This assumes that, as you have stated, you want to `AND` together some number of criteria only.